# Why isn't submission handler I add with hook_form_alter() called?

Tags: 8, webforms

The submission handler I add in `hook_form_alter()` isn't invoked. I tried the following code, but it doesn't work.

```php
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form,$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'FORMID') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'MODULENAME_form_submit';
  }
}

function MODULENAME_form_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  print_r($form_state);
}
```

How do I add a submission handler to a webform?

Comment: Did you try to add function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) ? Also instead of print_r use dsm (you need to enable devel module).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this :

```
  function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form,$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'FORMID') {
      foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
        if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
          $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = 'MODULENAME_form_submit';
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function MODULENAME_form_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    kint($form_state);
  }
```